# Title how does page no work in Twenty Eleven

Tags: title

I would like to understand how does twenty eleven title page no works..
    sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'twentyten' ), max( $paged, $page ) );

I dont understand the above part as in the __() function the arguments are $text and $domain what is $domain and how does %s print's no. Below is the whole code of title thank you

```
<title><?php
/*
 * Print the <title> tag based on what is being viewed.
 */
global $page, $paged;

wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );

// Add the blog name.
bloginfo( 'name' );

// Add the blog description for the home/front page.
$site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
    echo " | $site_description";

// Add a page number if necessary:
if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
    echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'twentyten' ), max( $paged, $page ) );

?></title>
```

Comment: can you explain in more detail what the problem is?

Comment: Hi Michael,
Actually there is no problem I wanted to understand How twentyten & twentyeleven are adding page number and why twentyten was being passed in __()
But Thanx to Dunc I understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so...

`sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'twentyten' ), max( $paged, $page ) );`

First off - [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php). Returns a `formatted string`, using variables and a type specifier to display information.

For example,

```
$house = "Mansion";
$house_number = 49;
sprintf( 'My house is a %s and its number is %d', $house, $house_number );
```

Will print `My house is a Mansion and its number is 49`.

Like you see in the Twenty Eleven theme, you can add functions to these variables:

```
$house = "Mansion";
$house_number = 49;
sprintf( 'My house is a %s and its number is %d', strtolower( $house ), $house_number );
```

Will print `My house is a mansion and its number is 49`.

---

Now, in the code you want to understand, there are two variables: `paged` and `page`, which are `global variables` defined by other WordPress scripts. One of those variables will return the current page number in a set of results - i.e. if you're on the fifth page of results, `paged` or `page` will be `5`.

However, I think there has been some discrepancy in the past between which of these variables gets used. This is why the [max](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) function is being used - the theme is looking to see which of those variables are actually set, then it displays it. `max` simply looks at an array of values and returns the highest. In this case, only one of these global variables will be set, and as such the `max` function is a quick and easy way of seeing which one is being used.

`sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'twentyten' ), max( $paged, $page ) );`

`%s` in this sprintf function indicates that the value of `max( $paged, $page )` should be displayed as a string.

If `$paged` was 4, `$page` wouldn't be set, so that line would display `Page 4`. Alternatively, if `$page` was being used, `$paged` wouldn't be set.

The `__( )` function is part of [WordPress localization](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress#Localization_Technology). Basically it allows for translations of your web-page to be written. This specific function simply `returns` the translated string; the `_e( )` function actually echoes it. The `twentyten` string of this argument is the `$domain`. I won't go into any more detail about that as I don't actually fully understand it myself.

If you remove the localization function, you'll see that the function works in exactly the same way:

`sprintf( 'Page %s', max( $paged, $page ) );`

---

Hope that helps - sorry for the "bitty" explanation.

Comment: Hi Thanx For explaining but why there is twentyten written since I am making my own theme should that be my themename instead of twentyten...

    sprintf( 'Page %s', 'twentyten', max( $paged, $page ) );

Comment: Hi I understood after reading 3 to 5 times sorry for being ignorant thanx for explaining...

Comment: Sorry tjrocks - I've just realised my last function was wrong, which might've made things confusing. `twentyten` in that example is simply the `$domain` argument for the localization function. I'll correct my post now :)

Comment: No problem got that things sorted...Thanx...by your explaination lots of things got clear...